# Compare 2 image pixel by javascript without use canvas tag

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 images pixels using javascript code and without the use of canvas tag. I want to do that by entering the range of the 2 images. I tried to use md5 but it's doesn't give me a detailed answer.

Comment: You can't do it without the canvas tag unless you can find a library to decode compressed image formats.

Comment: Becuse I want to insert two images with some differences among them and then I do a certain pixel comparing

Comment: @user3803761 That doesn't answer the 'Why without canvas'.  You are asking to do a job and then state you don't want to use the right tool to *do* that job.

Comment: if you read well you find me  answered the question "Why without canvas"

Comment: Nothing wrong with Jeremy's reading comprehension.  You still haven't answered: `Why without canvas?`

Comment: i can't do what i want with canvas

Comment: @user3803761 Why do you think you can't do what you want with canvas? Canvas seems to be the more appropriate way. Please explain in detail what you want, or why you don't want canvas.  Otherwise, you could fall into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to create a game where code includes the introduction of two images and then compared them work through a certain range of pixel

Comment: The answer to this question was "No that's not possible" at the time it was written but now that Array Buffers are available in JavaScript it's now possible to write an answer and say, "Yes and here's how".